# Automate GPG decryption using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, gnupg

I have been trying multiple different ways to decrypt using a Windows batch file. Moving the options around will a) cause the passphrase prompt to pop up or b) the batch file simply failing with a message that the passphrase was not found. There is lots of info online but most of them are old and no longer applicable to the newer version of GPG.

When I do get prompted for the passphrase the files decrypt just fine

Using GPG 2.2.19

Below is the line from the batch file. Can anyone see what is wrong? I understand putting the --password string in the batch-file is not good practice but there only 2 trusted admins on this Windows machine (Win 2012 R2) and we both need the decryption tasks automated.

Batch file:

```
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\"
GPG echo PASSPHRASE|gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback -o X:\OUTPUTDIRECTORY\FILENAME.CSV --passphrase-fd 0 -d X:\ENCRYPTEDFILEDIRECTORY\FILENAME.gpg
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is below. Note the quotes, absence of --batch, elimination of echo and PASSPHRASE|gpg. The placement of the options must be exactly like that. I have tested this numerous times and set up windows task scheduler to execute the batch file, everything runs perfect.

```
gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase "YOURPASSPHRASE" -d -o "X:\OUTPUT DIRECTORY\FILENAME.csv" "X:\ENCRYPTEDFILEDIRECTORY\FILENAME.gpg"
```